# List Util fastAny() function not resolved

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I am trying out Kotlin's List Util **`fastAny()`** function with this sample code:

```
fun main() {

    val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    val predicate = list.fastAny { it > 3 }

}
```

On `Android project` the function is resolving but it is not being resolved on `IntelliJ project.`
[image]

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you're using an [extention function](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/util/package-summary#(kotlin.collections.List).fastAny(kotlin.Function1)) from Compose which is Android specific. Kotlin's List does not have `fastAny` function if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store filtered (number > 5) numbers in predicate list, use this:

```
fun main() {

    val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    val predicate = list.filter{ it > 3 } 
}
```

There is not official extention function .fastAny{}.

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html#filter-by-predicate

Answer (score 0):

The insights above are correct - **`fastAny()`** is not part of the Kotlin Standard Library but rather a part of the Jetpack Compose library specifically from `androidx.compose.ui.util` package.

This is an except from the docs:

> Returns `true` if at least one element matches the given [predicate].
> Do not use for collections that come from public APIs, since they
> may not support random access in an efficient way, and this method may
> actually be a lot slower. Only use for collections that are created by
> code we control and are known to support random access.

This is the source code:

```
@Suppress("BanInlineOptIn")
@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun <T> List<T>.fastAny(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    contract { callsInPlace(predicate) }
    fastForEach { if (predicate(it)) return true }
    return false
}
```

The code is compiling on Android Studio because I have compose dependencies and have used this **`import androidx.compose.ui.util.fastAny.`**

I did further research and learnt `fastAny()` a utility function optimized for performance esp. on large lists by using indexed loops instead of iterator-based loops.

It is designed for use within Jetpack Compose projects for building UIs on Android.

There are also similar util fxns like *fastForEach(), fastForEachReversed(), fastForEachIndexed(),fastFirstOrNull(), fastSumBy()*  etc.

Comment: you should accept any of the answers instead of elaborating on top of other contributors

Comment: @Lino: That’s generally true, but this is offering significant additional value to the topic, and merits the additional post, regardless of what answer is ultimately accepted.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thanks, you read my mind. I only posted an additional answer after coming into more info on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody will find this useful - filtering classic, Predicate & BiPredicate:

```
import java.util.function.BiPredicate
import java.util.function.Predicate

class StackOverflow {


  fun filterListClassic(list: List<Int>, that: Int): List<Int> {
    return list.stream()
      .filter { biggerThanThatClassic(it, that) }
      .toList()
  }

  private fun biggerThanThatClassic(given: Int, that: Int): Boolean {
    return given > that
  }


  fun <T> filterListPredicate(list: List<T>, filter: Predicate<T>): List<T> {
    return list.filter { filter.test(it) }
  }

  val biggerThan3: Predicate<Int> = Predicate { that: Int -> that > 3 }


  fun filterListBiPredicate(list: List<Int>, biPredicate: BiPredicate<Int, Int>, that: Int): List<Int> {
    return list.stream()
      .filter { biPredicate.test(it, that) }
      .toList()
  }

  val biggerThanThat: BiPredicate<Int, Int> = BiPredicate { given: Int, that: Int -> given > that }

}

fun main() {
  val myList = listOf(2, 3, 5, 9, 1, 3, 7)

  StackOverflow().apply {
    val that = 3

    val filteredClassic = filterListClassic(myList, that)
    println(filteredClassic)

    val filteredPredicate = filterListPredicate(myList, biggerThan3)
    println(filteredPredicate)

    val filteredBiPredicate = filterListBiPredicate(myList, biggerThanThat, that)
    println(filteredBiPredicate)
  }
}
```